# Why can't methods have the same name in the same class?

Tags: smalltalk

You can't have methods with the same name in the same class in Smalltalk. Why?

I don't understand why methods can't have same name in same class.

Comment: Please explain what are you trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

You are probably thinking about [function overloading](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.3.0?topic=only-overloading-functions-c) in languages like C++ in which you can have multiple functions/methods with the same name but different parameter types or count. The difference is that in [dynamic programming languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming_language) like Smalltalk the type is associated with the object not the variable and so a variable can hold any type and the compiler doesn't know the type. So there would be no way to distinguish between functions/methods with the same name.